# How do I obtain the file-name from an outlook message file, by using Apache Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am creating a java Rest App, which extracts metadata from emails. I am trying to get the filename of the email `.msg` file

```
       tikaMetadata = new Metadata();
       System.out.println(tikaMetadata.get("resourceName") );  Metadata
```

I have tried various ways, but nothing has worked yet .  I think it may be in format similar to "Message:Raw-Header:Title" .

I also looked up the library Apache POI  .  Could it be in there ?

Comment: Don't you have the filename before you send the file to Tika?